# Release and Renew Ip won't work

Tags: dhcp, isp

I recently asked a question after someone online directed me to a link giving them my ip adress.

I got some great help and advice and was told to release and renew my ip adress so the hacker couldn't find my router anymore.

However, after watching youtube videos and trying to run the change through the terminal on my mac and the command prompt on my windows, neither work.

When I Google "what's my ip" it's still the same as before. Can anyone tell me what it is I'm doing wrong?

I ran the `ipconfig /release` then `ipconfig /renew` on windows and `alias renew="sudo ipconfig set en0 BOOTP && sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP"` on my MAC. Neither changed my address.

Answer (score 3):

Your IP address is assigned by your ISP. When you disconnect and reconnect, you may get a different one from your ISP's address pool, or you may get the same. With some ISP, you always get the same, with others the chance of getting the same twice in a row is negligible, and with others it depends on the state of their load balancing equipment.

Revealing your IP address is *privacy* exposure (it reveals what geographical area you live in and who your ISP is) but it is not a *security* issue. If you want to be safe from “hackers”, hiding your IP address won't help — most hackers just wait until (or trick you into) visiting a website, and at that point they have your IP address and they're running Javascript code in your browser. To keep safe from hackers, make sure your operating system and browser are up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

The most common setup in home is:

```
                                    ((|))               Laptop
                                      |
ISP  ----------------------- Multi device ------------- Desktop 1
        (fibre or DSL                    \
         or cable)                        -------------- Desktop 2
```

The dashes are supposed to be wired connections.

The (( | )) is supposed to look like  an antenna for wireless.

'Multi device' stand for:
1) Firebre modem or cabele modem or DSL modem or ...
2) **and** build in firewall
3) **and** build in switch
4) **and** build in wireless access point
5) **and** build in **DHCP server**
6) **and** act as a router.

TYping 'ipconfig /release' or 'ipconfig /renew' act on your local computer. It will release the IP from the desktop or laptop. It will then ask the multi device for a new one.

In short, this does:

1. Not change the IP on your multi device. That is the public IP anoyone can use to find you.
2. Is does change the private (most likely 192.168.x.x./24) address on your internal network. An IP which is never shown outside your house. It is a non routable RFC1918 address.

Now you could log in on the multi device (aka 'router' though that really is a wrong name) and do an IP release there. Then request a new one. Since it is unlikely to run windows (probably an embedded Linux or similar) the command would differ. And you are likely to get the same IP back.

The last because IP addressses and DHCP usually are implemented like this:

DHCP server:
Gets a range of IP to handle out.
Has a list of IPs handled out before.

DHCP client: (aka your laptop or dekstop)  dhcd-req:
  'Hi, I am AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF, can someone please give me some information on how to work on this network?'

DHCP server:  dhcp-ack
  'Sure. Here is an IP. And if you want this is useful as the defautl gateway, and you might wabt to use this as nameserver. And you might want to use this as hostname. ....  This information is valid for this long (say 4 hours to make this an easy example).

DHCP client: now uses that for the next 2 hours. (half the lease time).

After there two hours:
A new DHCP request. The goal is to get a new lease which is valid for another 4 hours. This keeps the dynaminc IP address nicely stable.

The DHCP server has a log of handled out IPs.  It seems that the same MAC address is requesting the same IP **and handles out the same IP**.

This is used both internally by your multi-device and by the ISP. Requesting a new IP will likely get you the same IP. It does not woprk for hiding.

And that ignore the part where hiding is security by obscurity. But that would be a different question.